# Browser settings with complete restriction for cookies - Unable to display javascript messages

Tags: javascript, browser

I am working on a web application that uses a lot of javascript.
My situation now is that if the user has some settings in the browser blocking everything,  I cannot show any error messages.
Eg.: A request failed, login won't work, etc. I will not be able to use a custom function to display an error message. The javascript functions will all return undefined.

If the user applies some simple blocking restrictions (cookies) for example, I am still able to show the error messages.

In this case, what would be the workaround to give the users a warning that the browser has a complete restriction activated?

Comment: In general, the way to do this is to a) show the message by default b) remove it using the potentially blocked mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display to the user that Javascript needs to be enabled through the HTML tag `<noscript>`.

Such like:

```
<noscript>
    Javascript is disabled!
</noscript>
```